# PHP: Hashing or encrypting a shopping bag ID to store into cookie

Tags: php, cookies, encryption, hash

The items that a visitor has in his shopping bag are linked to a bagID.
If a user revised the site I like to show them there previous bag content.

I'm not sure which method, encryption or hasing to store the bagID  on a client pc cookie. 
The bag content isn't anything to be afraid of if others would know it.

**opt1: storing bagID + unique salt into user cookie**
Hashing bagID + salt gives access to the bag content. The salt is unique for each bag so
if someone retrieves this cookie from a user he only has access to the bag content of this specific user.

**opt2: encrypt the bagID.**
A disadvantage seems it would be slow to do it well.

**opt3:?**

If one of the two would be a good option what kind of hahsing or encryption algorithm would be recommendable for this situation?

Comment: So you edit the question and remove the opt3 *after* this became the answer? Would be nice if you could elaborate a bit.

Comment: "The bag content isn't anything to be afraid of if others would now it." this means the ability to add  items to another person's bag (which they'll be shipped and billed for) is nothing to be afraid of?

Comment: bagID = primary key of some table in a database? If not, why not? If so the way to do this is not to use cookies or anything like that which would rely on the client sending back some sensible data, but rather to create a table of bagID -> userID relationships (assuming a user can have multiple bagIDs over time, otherwise a bagID column in the users table will suffice) and use the userID to obtain the bagID(s). This way you can code your back end in such a way that no-one can view another user's bag unless they break into that user's account.

Comment: @Damon that's the reason I'm looking for a safe/good solution

Comment: @DaveRandom bagID is the primary key of a table. I was interested in finding out how sites like asos.com and yoox.com store the bag content (they use cookies I guess). You don't have to be singed in to keep your bag content.

Comment: @Rob That would probably involve 4 tables (at a guess, at least that's how I would do it). You have a `users` table, a `bags` table, an `items` table, and a `bag_items` table. `users` contains the master user information, username/pass/profile info, the usual stuff. `bags` is simply an ID (PK) and a FK field that references the user id that owns the bag (could have other associated data like a name for the bag). `items` are the items that can be added to a bag. `bag_items` holds information about which items are in which bag - a foreign key to `bags` and a foreign key to `items`.

Comment: So when you want to get a list of the bags for a user you do `SELECT id FROM bags WHERE user_id = $userID`

Comment: And to get a list of items in a specific bag you do `SELECT i.* FROM bag_items b JOIN items i ON i.id = b.item_id WHERE b.id = $bagID`.

Comment: And obviously there are much more complex queries that can be made to get items from a user ID and other such magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making it more complicated then it needs to be. Don't store `bagID` at all. Create unique hash for the bag, store it in a DB table for bags, and retrieve  bag contents based on that unique hash.

Comment: your right, thank you, this is how I've solved it using different salt for each hash as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand that you wish to store entire bag's content in client cookie? It is possible, but due to many limitations on cookie's length and content is not advised. Simply store all items in the bag in your local database, keyed by client ID.

SQL columns would go:

```
client_id (not unique), item_id, amount
(repeat for as many times as many positions you have)
```

In most no-SQL you can just use an array of objects.

And, BTW, this has nothing to do with PHP.